# Последние документы в RibbonApplicationMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, ribbon

Как правильно работать с этим меню "Последние документы"? Добавлять элементы списка и обрабатывать нажатия.

Что имею.
XAML

```
<Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
    <RibbonApplicationMenu>
        <RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>

            <RibbonGallery CanUserFilter="False" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" SelectionChanged="RibbonGallery_SelectionChanged">
                <RibbonGalleryCategory x:Name="ribbonGallery" Header="Последние документы" Background="Transparent" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                    <RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
                </RibbonGalleryCategory>
            </RibbonGallery>

        </RibbonApplicationMenu.AuxiliaryPaneContent>
    </RibbonApplicationMenu>
</Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
```

Добавляю коллекцию элементов (Последние открытые документы) - данные для теста

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var portObsCol = new ObservableCollection<RibbonGalleryItem>();

    portObsCol.Add(new RibbonGalleryItem() { Content = "documentPath/name1", Name = "Name1" });
    portObsCol.Add(new RibbonGalleryItem() { Content = "documentPath/name2", Name = "Name2" });

    ribbonGallery.ItemsSource = portObsCol;
}
```

Получаю: 
[image: Меню - Ribbon ApplicationMenu]

При клике по элементу

```
private void RibbonGallery_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
{
    RibbonGallery ribbonGallery = sender as RibbonGallery;
    MessageBox.Show(ribbonGallery.SelectedValue.ToString());
}
```

Получаю:
[image: Окно MessageBox]

Надеюсь, есть более удачны способ обработки клика и связывания? =))

---

Из примера с MSDN

Я не смог найти как забиндить динамический ресурс ({DynamicResource MostRecentFiles}) для элементов меню.
Как это можно реализовать в коде?

```
<ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory Header="Recent Documents" 
                              Background="Transparent" 
                              ItemsSource="{DynamicResource MostRecentFiles}">
    <ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" IsItemsHost="True"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory.ItemsPanel>
</ribbon:RibbonGalleryCategory>
```

Comment: Да, есть лучшие варианты. Выучите MVVM и связывайтесь через `Binding` к `DataContext`'у.

Comment: А динамический ресурс привязывать не надо. Список item'ов — это не UI-ресурс, это VM.